# Good IM/Chat solution for pasting code

Tags: chat, copy-paste

We've got several distributed developers working together on a couple of projects. We've been using Skype to host chats with all the developers, and it works okay except for one thing:

It REALLY mangles any code we copy and paste into the chats -- especially the whitespace in Python.

This question has tons of opinions about chat clients & servers, but no one has much to say about pasting in code. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415/best-chat-im-tool-for-developers)

Is anybody out there using a chat or im client that handles source code really well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Teamtalk](http://www.teamtalk.im/)

**Features**:

- SSL Security - Same as what banks use for online transactions.
- Source code highlighting in messages.
- Screen capture, Remote desktop, File transfer.
- IM, Conference, Groups, Send message to all/many.

Comment: This does what I was looking for... wish it was a client for a standard like XMPP though - with all the free options out there it'd be hard to justify a monthly charge for a chat program that only our devs use. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Matt keep me posted if you can find the same with XMPP support i'd be interested

Comment: The link is dead, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

There's [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)

Comment: Pastebin is a good option, but I'd consider it a work-around. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/):

"Gobby is a free collaborative editor supporting multiple documents in one session and a multi-user chat. It runs on Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, Linux and other Unix-like platforms."

Comment: Might be a good option - but it looks a little "heavyweight" for what I'm wanting to do. Thanks though.