# IM clients (or plugins) with code formatter / highlighter

Tags: syntax-highlighting, instant-messaging

Can anybody recommend an IM client (Linux / Mac preferred) that either support natively, or via a plugin the ability to format & highlight blocks of code that are pasted in chat windows? I'm constantly pasting and receiving blocks of code in my client (Adium at the moment) where I copy them out into an editor to perform the formatting to make it readable.

I know I can't be the only one that shuttles snippets of code around to others like this, so I figure someone must have done this already, but my searches are coming up with nothing.  Please someone help me before I throw my hands up and just start another time-sink project myself :)

Comment: @Green Hope this solves your problem too

Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505848/good-im-chat-solution-for-pasting-code

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at http://collabedit.com/